# Micronaut: I can't inject a bean with private constructor. Why?

Tags: micronaut

I injected a Bean via an Interface with field injection in a scheduled job.
When the implementation of that interface has a private constructor.

```
@Singleton
public class MyJob {

    @Inject
    private MyInterface bean;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = "3s")
    public void iwas() {
        System.out.println(bean.getsomeString());
    }
}
```

The implementation of MyInterface (lets call it MyImpl) is annotaed with @Singleton. It has an empty default constructor.
When I start the app, it prints the messages from MyImpl. But only if the constructor is not private. When its private, nothing happens. I dont even get a nullpointer exception.

I looked at the build-in beans - endpoint. In both cases the bean existed:

```
"org.example.$MyImpl$Definition": {
            "scope": "javax.inject.Singleton",
            "type": "org.example.MyImpl"
        }
```

What is happening? The debugger does not jump into the scheduled methode when the constructor of MyImpl is private

Comment: What version of Micronaut are you using? I get an error when running something similar with a private constructor with version 3.6.3.
Real question is how to you create the `MyImpl` bean if there is only a private constructor.

Comment: This does not answer your question, but why is it that you want to have a private constructor in a class that you are asking the framework to create an instance of for you?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Becaus emy team leader does not understand cdi. So when I used Singleton annotation he asked me: "And how do you make shure nobody else is creating an instance of this with the default constructor?" The Jakata Docus says: " The bean constructor is a default-access, public, protected or private constructor of the bean class." (https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/2.0/cdi-spec-2.0.html) So a private constructor should be possible.

Comment: @ShingJo I'm using 3.5.3. A private constructor should be possible due to the jakarta documentation.

Comment: @Zonko "The Jakata Docus says: " The bean constructor is a default-access, public, protected or private constructor of the bean class." (jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/2.0/cdi-spec-2.0.html)" - Does Micronaut implement CDI 2.0?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I think I got lost somewhere. Isn't CDI the same as Jakarta? And Micronaut supports Jarkata...so... Sorry. I think I am missing some basics.

Comment: "Isn't CDI the same as Jakarta?" - Maybe, but I don't think so.  I think CDI is a spec produced by Jakarta.  You are asserting that Micronaut should support private constructor injection because the CDI 2.0 spec says it should. I am asking if Micronaut implements CDI 2.0.  If not, then I don't think what that spec calls out should necessarily be considered an expectation of Micronaut's behavior.  If it does claim to implement CDI 2.0, then that would be a different scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Creator` see https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#introspection and scroll down to the "Static Creator Methods" section.

For example,

```
@Singleton
public class MyImpl implements MyInterface {

    private int count = 0;

    private MyImpl() {
        System.out.println("Private constructor for MyImpl");
    }

    @Override
    public String getsomeString() {
        return String.format("Getting String %d", ++count);
    }

    private static MyImpl instance = null;

    @Creator
    public static MyImpl getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new MyImpl();
        }

        return instance;
    }

}
```

Comment: FYI... In a comment above OP expressed that one of the concerns is "And how do you make shure nobody else is creating an instance of this", which this solution doesn't address.  They also said the motivation for doing this was "Becaus emy team leader does not understand cdi" - so the actual solution is likely education and using a non-private constructor.